# Varnish: 400 bad request for / only

Tags: apache, http, drupal, timeout, varnish

I have varnish server that is timing out only for requests coming to site `/` (https://example.com/) while all other requests being processed normally. Ex: (example.com/en)

The output of varnish log is:

```
*   << Request  >> 164200    
-   Begin          req 164199 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1676987476.561832 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1676987476.561832 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 36702 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ReqHeader      X-Real-IP: 10.254.27.52
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 10.254.27.52
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 10.254.27.52
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 10.254.27.52, 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      Surrogate-Capability: Varnish=ESI/1.0
-   ReqHeader      Host: 
-   ReqURL         /
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   Hit            3 2414.934756 120.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_call       HIT
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     400
-   RespReason     Bad Request
-   RespHeader     Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2023 13:31:31 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Apache
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 226
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
-   RespHeader     x-url: /
-   RespHeader     x-host: 
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 164200 3
-   RespHeader     Age: 1185
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespUnset      x-url: /
-   RespUnset      x-host: 
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0)
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 164200 3
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1676987476.561898 0.000066 0.000066
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1676987476.561937 0.000105 0.000040
-   ReqAcct        142 0 142 177 226 403
-   End
```

TCP Dump taken and this request is within the localhost and not actually reaching the server where apache is.

[image: TCP Dump]

`varnishd` is look like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
KillMode=process

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
LimitNOFILE=131072

# Locked shared memory - should suffice to lock the shared memory log
# (varnishd -l argument)
# Default log size is 80MB vsl + 1M vsm + header -> 82MB
# unit is bytes
LimitMEMLOCK=85983232

# Enable this to avoid "fork failed" on reload.
TasksMax=infinity

# Maximum size of the corefile.
LimitCORE=infinity

ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,2g -p http_max_hdr=1024 -p http_resp_hdr_len=65536
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/varnishreload

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are receiving an `HTTP/1.0` request. This doesn't include a `Host` header, because that version of the protocol doesn't support it.

However, Varnish converts it into an `HTTP/1.1` request, which requires the use of a `Host` header. As described in https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/#enforce-the-host-header the built-in VCL enforces that header and returns an `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` if it doesn't find the header.

I'm pretty sure this is related to a missing configuration in your TLS proxy. Please make sure it sends `HTTP/1.1` traffic and the problem should resolve itself.